# "Expected statement" in an If Then Statement

Tags: asp-classic, if-statement

I have a classic asp application, and i need to skip a for loop if the user has chosen to export this report into excel (the for loop paginates the results)

i'm trying to skip this, like so:

```
 if not wordExport then    
    response.Write "test"
    for J = 1 to RSList.PageSize
    end if
```

more code here display all the information from the database.(without pagination since the user has picked "export")

```
 if not wordExport then
    RSList.movenext
    next
    end if
```

however, i keep getting the following error:

```
Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0400'

Expected statement


end if
^
```

is there something i'm missing??? i don't see it... aaah. help!

Comment: Your question has become a bit of a mess, show us a small but complete example of the code that is failing (without intermediatory commentory) demonstrate the you understand that all `For` statements should have a corresponding `Next` and `If` have both a `Then` and an `End If`.  This exercise alone will probably highlight the problem to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had to do a workaround (which cause lots and lots of redundant code)

```
if wordExport then
Call DisplayAll()
else
Call DisplayWithPages()
end if
```

where these two subs are exactly the same, except one loops in increments of  20 (page size), and the other loops through the whole dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you don't even have a proper FOR loop to begin with.

```
 if not wordExport then    
    response.Write "test"
    for J = 1 to RSList.PageSize
    next   <-----
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

are you missing a Next J statement?

```
if not wordExport then    
    response.Write "test"
    for J = 1 to RSList.PageSize
    'Do Something
    Next J
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need a `Next` after your `for` loop